# Usage of porque, por qué, porqué, y por que

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática

> Trato de ayudarla +preposición+ no se deprima.

Which form of "because" would you use to fill in the blank in the sentence to complete it?

Comment: "Trato de ayudarla por que no se prima" is incorrect. I guess it should be "Trato de ayudarla para que no se deprima". Sentence too is translated to "S/he asked why s/he had come". Same use as in sentence 3: "I don't know why you have rejected that position".

Comment: @Lucas  I wasn't sure whether the sentence is incorrect.

Comment: I fixed the question to reflect the problem I have.

Comment: @Drew with the new form, it'll need to be *para que* unless you mean *deprime*. Are you trying to help to keep her from getting depressed, or helping her because she isn't getting depressed?

Comment: I understand that you must use para que. I'm right about the deprima because para que must follow subjunctive. I'm trying to help keep her from getting depressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para rellenar la frase "Trato de ayudarla _ no se deprima" no se usa ninguna de las opciones (porque, por qué, etc). En cambio, se dice:

"Trato de ayudarla para que no se deprima" (In english it might be "I try to help her so she doesn't depress")

Podría usarse "porque" en esta otra frase: "Trato de ayudarla porque está deprimida" ("I try to help her because she is depressed"), pero significa otra cosa.

Answer (score 6):

Please, [check the RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que) for a deep explanation of this.

You use *por qué* as two words and with the accents for questions:

> Por qué es eso así?
>
> Me pregunto por qué Jorge está tan enfadado.

Or in exclamation:

> Por qué sitios más bonitos hemos pasado de camino aquí!

Using *por que* in a question is a misspelling. You need the accent.

You use *porque*, as a single word and without the accent to explain something.

> Por qué llora el bebé?
> Llora **porque** tiene tiene hambre.

*Porqué*, is a noun.

> No comprendo el porqué de ese razonamiento. No comprendo el porqué (la razón) de eso.

*Por que* is the use of the preposition and the relative pronoun *que*, which is quite complex.

> Esa es la razón por que llora el bebé = Esa es la razón por **la** que llora el bebé.

But, please, check the link I gave you. It is really good. If you have problems understating that in Spanish tell us and we can help with some translations of those rules.

Comment: If you had to complete the sentence, Trato de ayudarla _ no se deprima, would you use porque, por qué, porqué, o por que? If you had to complete the sentence, Le avisé con tiempo _ viniera antes, which form of because would you use?

Comment: @Drew you need *para que* in both instances.

Comment: unrelated, where would the accent mark go on "decirmelo"?

Answer (score 2):

The quick rule:

> **porque = because**
>
> **por qué = why**

This is not the full story, though; see Diego's answer.